# How to find if a number is prime or not without division repeatedly

Tags: c, prime-factoring

I was told to make a program in C to find whether a number is prime or not and factorize it. I used repeated division method, i.e. I repeatedly divide the number by integers starting from 1 to that number, and if the remaining is 0 not more than 2 cases(1 and that number) the number is a prime number, otherwise it's not. But my teacher said that if a large number was there in input, the program would take much time to process it, so it was wrong. He said to create a new program but I can't understand how can I check if a number is prime or not without this method, so please anyone help me.

Comment: Or a more sophisticated method, like the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)…

Comment: @duskwuff: Miller-Rabin would help with identifying primes efficiently, but not factorization. We'd need to know how big a number we're talking about to determine which factoring algorithms are appropriate.

Comment: @Barmar: Sieve of Eratosthenes is good for primality testing many smallish numbers; a modified form could also factor them (but require significantly more memory to do so if you're storing factors for all of them). Either way, it's not ideal for the case where you need to primality test or factor just one large number; it replaces trial divisions with multiplications and memory, but it still scales relatively poorly, depending on what the teacher considers "large". The OP should be looking at [general factoring algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#General-purpose).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: The nice thing about Sieve of Eratosthenes is that you can pick a block size (e.g. `10!`, or `1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10`, or 3628800) and then copy (or recycle) the whole block in one go so that you don't need to care about the first N numbers; and you can increase the block size as much as you like (e.g. start with `2!` block and copy it 3 times and merge in the 3 to get a `3!` block, then do similar to get a `4!` block, then ..., up until you start running out of memory

Answer (score 1):

> I was told to make a program in C to find whether a number is prime or not and factorize it.

To start; forget about the "is prime or not" part and concentrate on the "factorize it" part.

To factorize a number; start by trying to divide by the smallest prime number, then the next smallest, then... Like this:

```
    while(value % 2 == 0) {
        printf("2 ");
        value /= 2;
        if(value == 0) {
            goto done;
        }
    }
    while(value % 3 == 0) {
        printf("3 ");
        value /= 3;
        if(value == 0) {
            goto done;
        }
    }
    while(value % 5 == 0) {
        printf("5 ");
        value /= 5;
        if(value == 0) {
            goto done;
        }
    }
```

This is going to get annoying, so let's switch to an array of prime numbers, maybe like this:

```
    unsigned int array[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 };

    for(index = 0; index < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); index++) {
        while(value % array[index] == 0) {
            printf("%u ", array[index]);
            value /= array[index];
            if(value == 0) {
                goto done;
            }
        }
    }
done: ;
```

Of course if there's only one factor then you know the number was prime, so let's add that:

```
    unsigned int array[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 };
    int factorCount = 0;

    for(index = 0; index < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); index++) {
        while(value % array[index] == 0) {
            printf("%u ", array[index]);
            value /= array[index];
            factorCount++;
            if(value == 0) {
                goto done;
            }
        }
    }
done:
    if(factorCount == 1) {
        printf("Yep, that's a prime number\n");
    }
```

Now, that array is going to get annoying too, especially for large numbers (who wants to write out a huge array of prime numbers by hand?). It'd be nicer to generate the list of prime numbers as you need them.

For that, you want "Sieve_of_Eratosthenes". For a description, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes